# modal window positioning help!

Tags: jquery, position, positioning, modal-dialog

I'm having problems with my modal window positioning. I've been trying to use $(document).height() and $(window).height() and its not giving me what I wanted. This will give me the right positioning if I'm on the top page, but if I scroll down somewhere on my page. The modal will position itself on the top page, and not where I'm viewing in the browser.

Someone please help me :) Been working on this for a long time

Thank you

jquery :

```
//Get the screen height and width
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();

        //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
        $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

        //transition effect     
        $('#mask').fadeIn(1);   
        $('#mask').fadeTo("fast",0.8);  

        //Get the window height and width
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();

        //Set the popup window to center
        id.css('top', (winH  - id.outerHeight()) / 2);
        id.css('left', ' (winW- id.outerWidth()) / 2);


        //transition effect
        id.show();
```

CSS

```
.imageBox .window {
left:0;
top:0;
text-align:center;
position:absolute;
display:none;
z-index:9999;
padding:20px;   
}
```

I don't want to use position:fixed; because if the modal window gets too large in height, I won't be able to scroll to the content that's outside of the window view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check how much you have scrolled to include it in your calculus, with:

```
var pixelsScrolled = $(document).scrollTop();
```

Hope this helps. Cheers